# Using a Lookup Table (PNG) to modify an Image

Tags: android, filtering, android-image

In my iOS application I use lookup tables (ColorLUT I believe) to modify/add a filter to my image. It works perfectly + its super fast. One of my tables is shown below.

**The question now is** - how can I achieve the same effect through Android? I know about a project call [JH Labs](https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/wiki/WorkStatus), which should contain the lookup feature, however I'm not really sure on how to use it as I'm unable to pass of the table PNG file as I would on iOS (via [GPUImageLookupFilter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)). Do I need to convert it somehow first, or how do I do it?

[image]

Comment: wth? why the down vote? It is a legit question.

Answer (score 1):

So while it's not a full answer, I think what you are looking for is something like [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html). There are a few predone filter like operations called [Intrinsics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsic.html) (More info on them [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/renderscript-intrinsics.html)).

Applying some of the basics of RenderScript, would allow you to take an image and compile it into an Allocation. This basically allows you to then send this to the parallel processors on the device and perform per unit memory operations on them. There are some issues with this mechanism being widely available/compatible across OS versions, however it seems more stable now than in years past. Originally it was very graphics oriented, and now it is more of a general computation framework that can be easily purposed for general graphics operations.